# Xcode / Application Uploader Fail To Submit App (Data Transfer Timeout)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, application-loader

I've been having problems submitting my iOS app update via Xcode's Organizer or Application Uploader today.

I've been submitting many app updates fine all these while, so the process is correct.

When I tried submitting the update today, I repeatedly got this "Data transfer timeout (40)" error after the "Verifying assess with the iTunes Store" stage.

Below is a screenshot of the error. I've tried using Xcode's Organizer or Application Uploader, but both show the same error. I've been trying for a few hours, but still the same result.

Is this due to some problem with their system, or has there been some change in Xcode / Application Loader since my last submission (about a month ago)?

There isn't any problems with my Internet connection, nor a firewall issue.

[image: Application Uploader Error]

Answer (score 1):

Apparently those "Data Transfer Timeout" errors were completely misleading. The actual problem lies in the "empty.o" file which somehow caused the ITMS-90035 error. This file has existed in all the previous compilations and it worked fine until now.

This file is compiled from the "empty.cpp" in my Cordova project's Resources subfolder. To resolve the problem, I went to Xcode > Project Settings > Build Phases > Compile Sources and removed that file, then archived the project again and the uploading / submission process went smoothly.